# Get "logged users" from "login history table" (session simulation)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID | username | domain | operation| datetime 
---+----------+--------+----------+--------------------
1  | john     | depA   | 'login'  | 2012-09-22 13:00:00
2  | mary     | depA   | 'login'  | 2012-09-22 13:10:00
3  | john     | depA   | 'login'  | 2012-09-24 13:25:00
4  | john     | depA   | 'logout' | 2012-09-24 13:55:00
```

I would like to get `(SELECT DISTINCT)` all "username, domain" which its last operation is login (which didn't logout by last) during the last 20 hours (datetime).

The idea is to get "all users currently at a session."

I would like the result to be processed in just one query.

Any ideas, please? I could not find a way of getting the result just with T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to filter out the date, and then use it twice in the query to get the most recent activity for each user:

```
;WITH RecentLogins AS
(SELECT username, operation, logdate
FROM logins
WHERE logdate >= DATEADD(hh, -20, GETDATE()))

SELECT r1.* 
FROM RecentLogins r1
WHERE logdate = (
    SELECT MAX(logdate) 
    FROM RecentLogins r2
    WHERE r1.username = r2.username AND r1.domain = r2.domain)
AND operation = 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATEADD`](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-dateadd-function.html) function and just use a negative number with it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, domain FROM table_name
WHERE operation = 'login' AND datetime >= DATEADD(Hour, -20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```